# Ooutput captured" takes ages until it appears on screen after multiple runs

Tags: java, timeout, fitnesse, fit-framework

I am wondering if other users already had the same issues. After tests have been run multiple times (guess ~30 times) the little "output captured" button takes ages until it appears on screen. The test ran normally (results at the top of the page are fine) but the page takes roundabout 30 more seconds until it finished loading and the "output captured" appears.

This seems to happen after multiple test runs. when i clean all the captured test history, logs and velocity logs everything is back to normal. So to me it looks as if fitnesse can't handle the folder structures (results?) anymore as they are growing and growing.

We are using fitnesse version "20100103".

Any help would be highly appreciated as it's not a real solution to always delete everything.

Comment: We experience the same, especially with tests that generate a lot of output on stdout. I don't know of a solution, sorry.

Comment: hi, the solution is to delete the error logs and history :)

src/main/fitnesse/FitNesseRoot/ErrorLogs
src/main/fitnesse/FitNesseRoot/files/testResults

Answer (score 0):

Earlier this year there were performance problems mainly due to the way variables were parsed. I would advice you to update to the latest version. I can remember that earlier this year there were some questions aout this topic regarding performance issues. You could check http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/fitnesse/

Comment: yes. we solved the problems by upgrading to the latest fitnesse version and cleaning the folders mentioned earlier.